# How to create a table only using <div> tag and bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have code below using table tag. But I want the same table using div tag. I have tried but could not make it same. Below I have attached the the image as well. Please help me out to create the same table using div tag.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Simple Tables</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bs-example{
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Carter</td>
                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Parker</td>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This isn't Bootstrap, this is just native HTML and CSS, but you can build table layouts (and table-like layouts) using:

- CSS Tables
- CSS Flex (with caution, see below)
- CSS Grid

Here's a quick primer:

---

## Table Layout using CSS Tables

You can create tabular layouts using **CSS Table** display values:

- `display: table` // `<table>`
- `display: table-header-group` // `<thead>`
- `display: table-row-group` // `<tbody>`
- `display: table-row` // `<tr>`
- `display: table-cell` // `<td>` & `<th>`

**Working Example:**

```css
/* HTML TABLE STYLES */

table thead {
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

table th, table td {
padding: 0 6px;
text-align: center;
}


/* CSS TABLE STYLES */

.css-table {
display: table;
}

.css-table-header {
display: table-header-group;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.css-table-body {
display: table-row-group;
}

.css-table-row {
display: table-row;
}

.css-table-header div,
.css-table-row div {
display: table-cell;
padding: 0 6px;
}

.css-table-header div {
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<table>
<thead>
<th>Row</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>Carter</td>
<td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Peter</td>
<td>Parker</td>
<td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>Rambo</td>
<td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<h2>CSS Table</h2>
<div class="css-table">
<div class="css-table-header">
<div>Row</div>
<div>First Name</div>
<div>Last Name</div>
<div>Email</div>
</div>

<div class="css-table-body">
<div class="css-table-row">
<div>1</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Carter</div>
<div>johncarter@mail.com</div>
</div>

<div class="css-table-row">
<div>2</div>
<div>Peter</div>
<div>Parker</div>
<div>peterparker@mail.com</div>
</div>

<div class="css-table-row">
<div>3</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Rambo</div>
<div>johnrambo@mail.com</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see the **HTML Table** and the **CSS Table** above look pretty much identical.

In general **CSS Tables** *are* a pretty good (if, arguably, underused) solution for elements which require tabular layouts.

But if you want to get use more sophisticated CSS tools - especially if you want table-like 2D layouts for things which aren't tables (e.g. User Interfaces) - you can use **CSS Flex** and **CSS Grid**.

---

## Table-like 2D Layout using CSS Flex

**N.B.** *Flexbox* isn't intended for complex 2-dimensional layouts and it's really far from ideal for tabular layout, so the example below is a proof-of-concept.

It can be done, but *it's really better not to use **Flexbox** for table-like layouts (or any other nested 2D layout).*

```css
.css-flex-table {
display: flex;
width: 80%;
}

.css-flex-table-header,
.css-flex-table-body {
display: flex;
flex: 0 0 100%;
}

.css-flex-table,
.css-flex-table-body {
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.css-flex-table-header div {
padding: 6px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.css-flex-table-header div,
.css-flex-table-body div {
flex: 0 1 100px;
padding: 0 6px;
border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.css-flex-table-header div:nth-of-type(4n),
.css-flex-table-body div:nth-of-type(4n) {
flex: 0 1 calc(100% - 308px);
}
```

```html
<div class="css-flex-table">

<div class="css-flex-table-header">
<div>Row</div>
<div>First Name</div>
<div>Last Name</div>
<div>Email</div>
</div>

<div class="css-flex-table-body">
<div>1</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Carter</div>
<div>johncarter@mail.com</div>

<div>2</div>
<div>Peter</div>
<div>Parker</div>
<div>peterparker@mail.com</div>

<div>3</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Rambo</div>
<div>johnrambo@mail.com</div>
</div>
</div>
```

---

## Table-like 2D Layout using CSS Grid

This is an ideal solution. **CSS Grid** is like *CSS Tables* on steroids.

```css
.css-grid-table,
.css-grid-table-header,
.css-grid-table-body {
display: grid;
}

.css-grid-table {
grid-template-rows: 24px 72px;
width: 80%;
}

.css-grid-table-header,
.css-grid-table-body {
grid-template-columns: 48px 110px 110px 180px;
width: 100%;
line-height: 24px; 
}

.css-grid-table-header {
grid-column-gap: 2px;
grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.css-grid-table-body {
grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.css-grid-table-header div {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: rgb(191, 191, 191);
}

.css-grid-table-body div {
padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-grid-table">

<div class="css-grid-table-header">
<div>Row</div>
<div>First Name</div>
<div>Last Name</div>
<div>Email</div>
</div>

<div class="css-grid-table-body">
<div>1</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Carter</div>
<div>johncarter@mail.com</div>

<div>2</div>
<div>Peter</div>
<div>Parker</div>
<div>peterparker@mail.com</div>

<div>3</div>
<div>John</div>
<div>Rambo</div>
<div>johnrambo@mail.com</div>
</div>
</div>
```